# Wordpress query with sub relations

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to have a `meta_query` with sub relations? I don't want one `relation` to apply to all of the query's arrays.

I tried this, but to no avail:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'event_type',
        'value' => 'session',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'event_video',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '>'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'event_summary',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'event_date_single',
        'value' => '',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'event_start_time',
        'value' => '',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
```

So `'relation' => 'OR'` should only apply between `event_video` and `event_summary`. Everything else is independent of one another. Is this possible somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this could be a `meta_query` limitation. [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) shows that you **can** use relations for meta queries, but as far as I see the limitation is that *you can only use **one kind of relation** for the whole `meta_query`*.

This means you can have a full `OR` or a full `AND` (default) relation between `meta_query` parameters, but you can never have them both combined, which is just what you want.

As I was not glad when I faced it at WP Codex, I went deeper in the matter by manually searching the code. So I found out that `WP_Query` calls `WP_Meta_Query` to parse `meta_query` parameters. This is `WP_Meta_Query`'s class constructor (you can find it in `wp-includes/meta.php` at line `643` in WP 3.6):

```
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param array $meta_query (optional) A meta query
 */
function __construct( $meta_query = false ) {
    if ( !$meta_query )
        return;

    if ( isset( $meta_query['relation'] ) && strtoupper( $meta_query['relation'] ) == 'OR' ) {
        $this->relation = 'OR';
    } else {
        $this->relation = 'AND';
    }

    $this->queries = array();

    foreach ( $meta_query as $key => $query ) {
        if ( ! is_array( $query ) )
            continue;

        $this->queries[] = $query;
    }
}
```

Long story short, the second `if` shows that this class will work only either with a `OR` or `AND` relation, but ***never** with both of them combined*.

So, unfortunately, it seems that it's not possible to achieve what you are trying to do (at least until WP 3.6). I guess your best shot is to split the main query, first doing specific [Meta Queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) and then applying their results(returned `metas`) to your main query.

I know that this is not a solution but an answer. Nevertheless, I hope this may help you to find a solution for this matter.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this more and providing a good explanation! It's unfortunate it's not possible, at the moment at least. Hopefully I can whip something together to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @scferg5 alright! I would like to know how you passed by this when you solve it, if you'd like to share!