# How do I combine these two Wordpress search queries?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two search queries. One searches in the default manner, for any post titles that match the arguments.

The second query is set to search any posts with the postmeta key of "SKU" LIKE the search query.

I am trying to combine these two queries so that the search will return any posts whose title OR sku match the search term.

First query:

```
$args = array(
            's'                     => apply_filters('yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_search_query', $search_keyword),
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'orderby'               => $ordering_args['orderby'],
            'order'                 => $ordering_args['order'],
            'posts_per_page'        => apply_filters('yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_posts_per_page', get_option('yith_wcas_posts_per_page')),
            'meta_query'            => array(
                array(
                    'key'           => '_visibility',
                    'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                    'compare'       => 'IN'
                )
            )
        );
```

Second query:

```
        $args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'orderby'               => $ordering_args['orderby'],
        'order'                 => $ordering_args['order'],
        'posts_per_page'        => apply_filters('yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_posts_per_page', get_option('yith_wcas_posts_per_page')),
        'meta_query'            => array(
            array(
                'key'           => '_visibility',
                'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
                'compare'       => 'IN'
            ),
        array(
            'key'           => '_sku',
            'value'         => apply_filters('yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_search_query', $search_keyword),
            'compare'       => 'LIKE'
        )
        )
    );
```

How can I combine these two queries, and return any posts with the title or the sku matching the search term?

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you, but you might be about to have a problem combining those _meta_queries_. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966416/wordpress-query-with-sub-relations/18971049#18971049). In your second query, you have 2 meta_queries combined in an `AND` relation, and you need to combine these two conditions to the condition of the first query using `OR` relation, which does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you will be using args in the loop.

You can use the loop to add all the returned post_ids to an array.  You could run two seperate loops, and add all the entries to an array.  You would need to check for double entries, so you don't end up printing the same post twice.

So you would do something like-

```
//First loop    
$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'orderby'               => $ordering_args['orderby'],
    'order'                 => $ordering_args['order'],
    'posts_per_page'        => apply_filters('yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_posts_per_page', get_option('yith_wcas_posts_per_page')),
    'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key'           => '_visibility',
            'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
            'compare'       => 'IN'
        ),
    )
);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $my_post = my_post_function($post_id);
    //Store the items in an array
    $my_post_array [] = $my_post;
    query_posts($args); 
    endwhile;

 //Second loop 
  $args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'orderby'               => $ordering_args['orderby'],
    'order'                 => $ordering_args['order'],
    'posts_per_page'        => apply_filters('yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_posts_per_page', get_option('yith_wcas_posts_per_page')),
    'meta_query'            => array(
     array(
        'key'           => '_sku',
        'value'         => apply_filters('yith_wcas_ajax_search_products_search_query', $search_keyword),
        'compare'       => 'LIKE'
    )
    )
);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $my_post = my_post_function($post_id);
    //Store the items in an array
    $my_post_array [] = $my_post;
    query_posts($args); 
    endwhile;

//Remove duplicate entries from the array
array_unique ( $my_post_array, SORT_STRING );
```

Comment: I didnt quite do this exactly, but I used it as a great base to get what I needed. Thank you so much for your input!