# Wordpress woocommerce, sort by featured, New (with date range), menu order then title

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I am trying to set my default sort for my products in WordPress with Woocommerce to show me all the featured products first, then any new products that are no older than 120 days, then show everything else by menu order and finally by the title. Below is my initial code that does kind of do what i want but i have no idea how to set a date range of 120 days or newer.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
  if(!$_GET['orderby']) {
    $args['orderby'] = array( 
      'meta_value' => 'DESC', 
      'date' => 'DESC', 
      'menu_order' => 'ASC', 
      'title' => 'ASC'
    );      
    $args['meta_key'] = '_featured';
    return $args;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so I have done some searching and i found some code that is supposed to loop through arguments and then remove duplicates, being a noob I am not sure what I am missing. My code below gets an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on null` so i tried to add `$loop = new WP_Query( $args );` but then the code does nothing. So I am lost and looking for some clues on what i need to fix. Thanks!

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $my_post_array ) {
    if(!$_GET['orderby']) {
      //First loop - show featured
      $args['orderby'] = array( 'meta_value' => 'DESC' );
      $args['meta_key'] = '_featured';    


      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
          $post_id = get_the_ID();
          $my_post = my_post_function($post_id);
          //Store the items in an array
          $my_post_array [] = $my_post;
          query_posts($args); 
      endwhile;


      //Second loop - Show newer than 6 months 
      $args = array(   
          'orderby' => 'date',
          'order' => 'DESC',
          'date_query' => array(
          array(
              'before' => '6 months ago',
              ),
          )
      );

      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
          $post_id = get_the_ID();
          $my_post = my_post_function($post_id);
          //Store the items in an array
          $my_post_array [] = $my_post;
          query_posts($args); 
      endwhile;

      //Third loop - show everything else and sort by menu_order and title
      $args['orderby'] = array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'title' => 'ASC' );

      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
          $post_id = get_the_ID();
          $my_post = my_post_function($post_id);
          //Store the items in an array
          $my_post_array [] = $my_post;
          query_posts($args); 
      endwhile;

      //Remove duplicate entries from the array
      array_unique ( $my_post_array, SORT_STRING );

  }
}
```

**Update 2**

I have yet to have any luck, any chance someone can take a look at my latest code above and give me some ideas on a direction to try? This loop does not seem to work for this filter when adding to the functions.php, maybe i need to do something different. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You probably can't get that from a single query.  You'll have to limit ALL posts to those within the past 120 days, and so if you had any featured products older than that, they would be excluded.

Comment: @cale_b Can I do 2 or 3 querys? I am new to this but what if i query all posts and get just the featured then just the new that are not featured no older than 120 days and finally everything else? I just have no idea if that is possible or how to go about it.

Comment: Yes, that's what you'd want to do.  Two queries.  And you'd probably need to do this in a template (The two queries), and then load the relevant template part(s) so you don't have to duplicate the code within the loops.  Keep in mind the WooCommerce template override system, also: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: @cale_b Ok so I understand most of what your saying, I just have no idea how to accomplish it. I am guessing I would override the orderby loop template in my theme but any ideas on how I would write the functions? I can't seem to find anything about setting a date range. I will also have to do some research on how to do multiple queries, like I said, very new to this. Thanks!

Comment: OK, to help more, I'd need to know which page you are trying to display this on.  Is it the "default" product listing? All product listings? Category listings? etc.

Comment: All product listings, so any page that lists products, not category pages. I have a number of categories and this just needs to work on the "Default Sorting" in the dropdown or each one of those pages.

Comment: Also - keep in mind the rich variety of WooCommerce shortcodes - could you do this by dropping in two or three shortcodes: `[featured_products per_page="12"]` and then `[recent_products per_page="12"]`, and then `[products]` for example?

Comment: That is a good suggestion, the only problem is we need all featured to be listed and new before the rest of the products and need to make sure we are not showing duplicates. Also there are a different number of featured and new products for each category so i can't set limits on it especially since they change frequently. Then users who can't code need to be able to set it and forget it, it is simple to add a product or mark it featured.

Comment: OK, now what you're asking for is very different / complicated, because you don't want duplicates either.  You're going to need to hire a web developer, this question is beyond the reasonable scope of an SO answer.

Comment: I was afraid of that.. i was just looking at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775346/how-do-i-combine-these-two-wordpress-search-queries that combines 2 queries and removes duplicates... Guess i am going to have to figure this out on my own... well any other help you can offer i would appreciate!

Comment: @cale_b any chance you can help me get on the right track but not worry about duplicates? So my "Default  Sorting" dropdown does everything i need?