# How do I query taxonomy OR custom field in Wordpress at the same time?

Tags: wordpress

I need to query wordpress posts returning results that could be matched either by the category OR custom field. Using the below code only returns results if they are matched by the category AND custom field. I need to find matches where it could be matched by either query, so an "OR" result but doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help?

```
$args =  array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'tax_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'category',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'arts','food' ),
        'operator'  => 'IN'
    )
),
'meta_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'birth_city',
        'value' => 'London',
        'compare' => 'IN',
      ),
   )
);
```

Comment: I am _not sure_, but I think the odds are that this is not possible. This question reminded me of one [I answered a while ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18966416/2752041), it's not exactly the same, but I believe the same concept apply. The way I see, _meta_ and _tax_ queries are not related to each other, so it may not be possible to do a `OR` relation between them. I haven't dug through the code this time, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I think it's possible using `WP_Tax_Query` and `WP_Meta_Query`, I'm going have a look.

Comment: @birgire please do! I'll be glad to _hear_ there is a solution! :)

Comment: I guess the other solution would be actually writing a MySQL query?

Comment: Yeah, what I meant by _not possible_ was using `query_posts` or similar. I only use a written MySQL Query in the worst case scenario, when I really don't have any other choice, which seems to be this case.

Comment: @mathielo I gave it a shot ;-) Maybe you guys can refine it further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Version 0.2

Here's a simplification of my previous answer - I hope you don't mind me adding it as a new answer, to avoid confusion with my previous one.

Here I use the WordPress functions `get_meta_sql()` and `get_tax_sql()`, to modify the `WHERE` part of the SQL   generated by `WP_Query()`:

```
 /**
 * Class WPSE_OR_Query 
 * 
 * Add a support for (tax_query OR meta_query) 
 *
 * @version 0.2
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/22633399/2078474
 *
 */
class WPSE_OR_Query extends WP_Query 
{       
    protected $meta_or_tax  = FALSE;
    protected $tax_args     = NULL;
    protected $meta_args    = NULL;

    public function __construct( $args = array() )
    {
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'pre_get_posts' ), 999 );
        add_filter( 'posts_where',   array( $this, 'posts_where' ),   999 );
        parent::__construct( $args );
    }
    public function pre_get_posts( $qry )
    {       
        remove_action( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ) );            
        // Get query vars
        $this->meta_or_tax = ( isset( $qry->query_vars['meta_or_tax'] ) ) ? $qry->query_vars['meta_or_tax'] : FALSE;
        if( $this->meta_or_tax )
        { 
            $this->tax_args  = ( isset( $qry->query_vars['tax_query'] ) )  ? $qry->query_vars['tax_query']  : NULL;
            $this->meta_args = ( isset( $qry->query_vars['meta_query'] ) ) ? $qry->query_vars['meta_query'] : NULL;
        }
    }
    public function posts_where( $where )
    {       
        global $wpdb;       
        $field = 'ID';
        remove_filter( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ) );    

        // Construct the "tax OR meta" query
        if( $this->meta_or_tax && is_array( $this->tax_args ) &&  is_array( $this->meta_args )  )
        {
            // Tax query
            $sql_tax = get_tax_sql( $this->tax_args, $wpdb->posts, $field );            

            // Meta query
            $sql_meta = get_meta_sql( $this->meta_args, 'post', $wpdb->posts, $field );

            // Modify the 'where' part          
            if( isset( $sql_meta['where'] ) && isset( $sql_tax['where'] ) )
            {
                $where  = str_replace( array( $sql_meta['where'], $sql_tax['where'] ) , '', $where );
                $where .= sprintf( ' AND ( %s OR  %s ) ', substr( trim( $sql_meta['where'] ), 4 ), substr( trim( $sql_tax['where'] ), 4 ) );              
            }
        }   
        return $where;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here's a simplified version](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190011/wp-query-to-show-post-from-a-category-or-custom-field/190018#190018) of my answer. It adds a direct support for this into `WP_Query`. Let's call it version 0.3 ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the first attempt to solve your problem. I worked within the following restrictions:

- don't write the SQL query directly
- extend the `WP_Query`
- use `WP_Tax_Query` and `WP_Meta_Query`
- don't use `preg_replace`/`str_replace` on the SQL query.

This is maybe too restrict, but it's a challange ;-)

So you could try:

```
$args =  array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_or_tax' => TRUE,
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'birds','falcons' ),
                'operator'  => 'IN'
            )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'birth_city',
                'value' => 'London',
                'compare' => 'IN',
            ),
    )
);

$q = new WPSE_OR_Query( $args );
```

where we introduce the new parameter `meta_or_tax`:

```
`meta_or_tax` => FALSE
```

will give you the normal `WP_Query` behaviour and

```
`meta_or_tax` => TRUE
```

will allow you to get `OR` instead of the default `AND` between the *tax query* and the *meta query*.

The new `WPSE_OR_Query` class is defined as:

```
 /**
 * Class WPSE_OR_Query
 *
 * Add a support for (tax_query OR meta_query) 
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/22616337/2078474
 *
 */
class WPSE_OR_Query extends WP_Query 
{       
    protected $meta_or_tax  = FALSE;
    protected $tax_args     = NULL;
    protected $meta_args    = NULL;

    public function __construct( $args = array() )
    {
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( $this, 'pre_get_posts' ), 10 );
        add_filter( 'posts_clauses', array( $this, 'posts_clauses' ), 10 );
        parent::__construct( $args );
    }

    public function pre_get_posts( $qry )
    {       
        remove_action( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ) );            
        // Get query vars
        $this->meta_or_tax = ( isset( $qry->query_vars['meta_or_tax'] ) ) ? $qry->query_vars['meta_or_tax'] : FALSE;
        if( $this->meta_or_tax )
        { 
            $this->tax_args = ( isset( $qry->query_vars['tax_query'] ) ) ? $qry->query_vars['tax_query'] : NULL;
            $this->meta_args = ( isset( $qry->query_vars['meta_query'] ) ) ? $qry->query_vars['meta_query'] : NULL;
            // Unset meta and tax query
            unset( $qry->query_vars['meta_query'] );
            unset( $qry->query_vars['tax_query'] );
        }
    }

    public function posts_clauses( $clauses )
    {       
        global $wpdb;       
        $field = 'ID';
        remove_filter( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ) );    
        // Reconstruct the "tax OR meta" query
        if( $this->meta_or_tax && is_array( $this->tax_args ) &&  is_array( $this->meta_args )  )
        {
            // Tax query
            $tax_query = new WP_Tax_Query( $this->tax_args );
            $sql_tax = $tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, $field );
            // Meta query
            $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $this->meta_args );
            $sql_meta = $meta_query->get_sql( 'post', $wpdb->posts, $field );
            // Where part
            if( isset( $sql_meta['where'] ) && isset( $sql_tax['where'] ) )
            {
                $t = substr( trim( $sql_tax['where'] ), 4 );
                $m = substr( trim( $sql_meta['where'] ), 4 );
                $clauses['where'] .= sprintf( ' AND ( %s OR  %s ) ', $t, $m );              
            }
            // Join/Groupby part
            if( isset( $sql_meta['join'] ) && isset( $sql_tax['join'] ) )
            {
                $clauses['join']    .= sprintf( ' %s %s ', $sql_meta['join'], $sql_tax['join'] );               
                $clauses['groupby'] .= sprintf( ' %s.%s ', $wpdb->posts, $field );
            }       
        }   
        return $clauses;
    }

}
```

Here's an example of the normal SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (15,70) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'birth_city' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('London')) ) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

and the SQL of the modified version:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
AND ( ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'birth_city' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('London')) ) OR ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (15,70) ) ) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

This can of course be refined much more and you can hopefully extend it further to your needs.

Hope this help.

Comment: Wow, nice approach! I'll take a closer look later today and see if it's possible to do a more global approach such as `'relation' => 'OR', array('meta_query' => [...], 'tax_query' => [...])`, but not sure how possible/viable is that. We should try to improve it as much as we can and then [submit as a request](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback) for further WordPress updates :)

Comment: I wasn't expecting that, amazing!! I will be giving this a try, you really know your stuff! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @mathielo yeah, this would be an excellent feature to be integrated into wordpress

Comment: @user3452572 Great to hear it worked for you. I just posted version `0.2`, sorry for the extra answer ;-) It's an interesting question you posted. I agree with you and @mathielo that it would be handy to have this option. It would also be good to have more control of the generated SQL in `WP_Query()`, for example the part coming from the **tax query**. There exists a `get_meta_sql` filter but I couldn't find a corresponding `get_tax_sql` filter. If it existed we might use it to construct version `0.3` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I failed to find a way of how to do it with WP_Query, but if it helps, here is how to manually write the query, it looks ugly but if that is the only way it will serve the purpose:

```
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
        WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' 
        AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'                  
        AND $wpdb->terms.name IN ( %s, %s ) 
        OR ( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = %s
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = %s )
        ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
    ", 'arts', 'food', 'birth_city', 'London' ), OBJECT_K );
```

Comment: Although this query works, some optimization is needed to get only the data that you need, also, improper use of $wpdb class is dangerous if is not performed well. On the other hand, answer from @birgire shows excellent programming skills, and that it can be done with WP_Query class. Personally, I would just make two queries to the database, it's simple and safe.