# Making a taxonomy along with a meta_query (One or the other)

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make a WP_Query on a sites DB but I need to return articles that have the parameters in a tax-query OR a certain tag OR the parameters in a meta_query... How do I do that?

I know how to put together a WP_Query loop I just need to know how to assemble the $args variable.

Here is what I have thus far (just able to filter for things that that have all three):

```
$related_query_args = array(
                'tax-query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array($symbol . '-stock-news', $symbol . '-stock-news-stock-ticker')
                    ),
                ),
                'tag'       => $symbol,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'stock_ticker',
                        'value' => $stock_symbol_dollar_sign
                    ),

                ),
                'showposts' => 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta_query and tax_query work together just fine. the only thing i can think of is that you are query taxonomy by slug and passing the term id which are two different things, change:

```
'field'     => 'slug',
```

with

```
'field'     => 'id',
```

in your tax_query.

Comment: This will do a query for posts that have the meta_field AND the category. I need meta_field OR the category.... I don't think WP currently has this functionality? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611782/how-do-i-query-taxonomy-or-custom-field-in-wordpress-at-the-same-time    And that guys solution didn't seem to work for me either :(